# Android PHP Data Insertion Issue

Tags: php, android

Here I have created an android Application for Inserting some data to PHP Mysql Database. So, here i am first explaining whats happening in code of mine. I have created two fields Name and Address, Layout is nice. Now when I am clicking the insert button, success message coming and data too going into data rows creation is working, but the issue is data going blank, means fields strings are not going into DB.

Below is the Code:

```
package com.oplo.user.listing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextAdd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
    }
    public void insert(View view){
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();

        insertToDatabase(name,add);
    }
    private void insertToDatabase(String name, String add){
        @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "ResourceType"})
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String paramUsername = params[0];
                String paramAddress = params[1];


                 String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                 String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", add));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://xyz.in/demo.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, add);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Below is the PHP Code

```html
<?php
  define('HOST','asdasd.in');
  define('USER','sadsad');
  define('PASS','sadasd');
  define('DB','asdasdasd');
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];

    $sql = "insert into Persons (name,address) values ('$name','$address')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'success';
  }
  else{
    echo 'failure';
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please check the code and let me the error place in this Program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are already using MySQLi, it is worth using parameter binding (and it is really quite easy to do). At present you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your function insertToDatabase() has two string variables  'name' and 'add' as an arguments. You have same names of the new variables within this function.This might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that You are using single quotes for Your query. This way variables are not being pulled. Double-quoted string will interperet Your variables as variables not as string. 
Replace Your sql with:

```
$sql = "insert into Persons (name,address) values ('${name}','${address}')";
```

This is a really bad practice to insert raw data into the database mate... Try using prepared statements or mysqli::real_escape_string or at least filter them with filter_input() function